# Test Terraform plans on mock Azure environment

Tags: azure, testing, terraform, localstack

I am looking for a way to create Terraform plans and execute them on a mock Azure environment without provisioning any resources.
Coming from an AWS background I could use something like [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) and run my Terraform code upon the API provided by the LocalStack container, without the need to provision any actual resources.

Is there an equivalent for Azure?

Comment: No, there isn't. We are actively exploring Azure at LocalStack and we would be happy to receive any initial comments on how a mock Azure environment should look for you :)

Comment: @HarshMishra, if you are willing to do that, maybe starting by Azure's APIs would be awesome.